# Reinitialise DataTables with HTML (DOM) sourced data without loosing the data in the dom

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, knockout.js, datatables

we have a rather complex structure and combination of technologies for generating a table at the end.

We have a custom binding ,in that custom binding I initialize the datatables with `$('.DataTables').DataTable();` in the `init`(Knockout), this works fine if the data is already present.

But for the case, where the data will be loaded later ,because of an AJAX-Request, this does not work.

I need something to reinitialize the DataTable, with data which is present in the HTML(the data is already present in the html, but clicking on any column for sorting will make the data disappear).

What can I do ?

Now

Comment: Show us the custom binding. Usually, you store the data in an `observable` property of your viewmodel. In your ajax callback, you set this observable property. In the `init` of your custom binding, you create a dependency to the observable value and specify the refresh logic.

Answer (score 0):

Process to re initialize data table:

```
$('#theID').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

This will reinitialize datatable loading new data if any.

Comment: hi, thanks, but this doesnt work. The data is already in the dom but it had been filled by knockout. So after the `update` has been hit, knockout will fill in the data with this `<tbody data-bind="foreach: @knockoutArray">`,  but datatables does not recognise the new data pushed into the table and clicking on a column will making disappear all the data or will drop that data